# Zeros in pivot position

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

When zero appears in a pivot position, 
$$
A = LU
$$
is not possible.

What do we have to do here to make A=LU possible then? Do we have to find a specific P (permutation matrix) for A and continue afterwards. Or can't we just create a  U out of the original A w/o using a permutation matrix and rotate the U afterwards? I used to do the method described in the latter, but it seems like this method is wrong according to the introduction of the question.

Anyway let's get back to the question

SHOW directly why these are both impossible:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
2 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
l & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
d & e\\
0 & f\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
l & 1 & 0 \\
m & n & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
d & e & g \\
0 & f & h \\
0 & 0 & i \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I managed to solve the first one but couldn't at the 2nd

$$
Ax = B
$$

equation.

Comment: no one? Come on guys it's very simple I know. just a little bit of help is all i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can go directly to matrix $U$ starting from $A$ (through row operations without altering rows), then it is possible for $A$ to be written as $A=LU$. In other case, no.

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&0\\ 1&1&2\\ 1&2&1\end{bmatrix}\overset{R'_2:=R_2-R_1}{\longrightarrow}
\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&0 \\ 0&0&2 \\ 1&2&1 \end{bmatrix}\overset{R'_3:=R_3-R_1}{\longrightarrow}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0\\
0&0&2\\
0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Notice, that we have to alter the second and the third row in order to get to an upper triangular matrix. Thus, it is impossible for $A$ to be written as $LU$.